# ANSIBLE: Adding VMware ESX server to Vcenter Failing though Ansible vmware_host module: Certificate Error

Tags: python, ansible, pyvmomi, vmware-server

I am trying to add an ESX host to a vcenter server using Ansible code and vmware_host module. It's failing in Certification validation. is there any workaround for this ?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
       - name: Add ESXi Host to VCSA
         local_action:
           module: vmware_host
           hostname: xxxxxxxxxx
           username: administrator@vsphere.local
           password: xxxxx
           datacenter_name: Datacenter
           cluster_name: cluster1
           esxi_hostname: xxxxx
           esxi_username: root
           esxi_password: xxxx
           state: present
```

here is the output of my task:

```
xxxx@ubuntu:/etc/ansible$ sudo ansible-playbook sample.yml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Add ESXi Host to VCSA] ***************************************************
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `validate_certs: False` to your task:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
       - name: Add ESXi Host to VCSA
         local_action:
           module: vmware_host
           hostname: xxxxxxxxxx
           username: administrator@vsphere.local
           password: xxxxx
           datacenter_name: Datacenter
           cluster_name: cluster1
           esxi_hostname: xxxxx
           esxi_username: root
           esxi_password: xxxx
           state: present
           validate_certs: False
```

Comment: Oh yes actually i tried that as mentioned by otrher people in forums but looks like this parameter is no more supported.                                  
 ansible-playbook sample.yml
 

TASK [Add ESXi Host to VCSA] ***************************************************
fatal: [localhost -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "unsupported parameter for module: validate_certs"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Comment: @user3802947 Ehhh :/